# Как изменить цвет рамки окна highlightbackground и highlightcolor через call()?

Tags: tcl

**Задача:** хочу изменить цвет рамки окна tk.Tk() highlightbackground и highlightcolor через call().

**Получилось:** изменить через tcl, но не допру как пользоваться call... Есть какая-то инструкция?

**Нашел как пользоваться:**

```
#root.overrideredirect(1)
#root.after_idle(root.attributes, '-topmost', True)

root.call('wm', 'overrideredirect', '.', 1)
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call()- это метод который является интерфейсом к базовому интерпретатору tcl. Это позволяет вам создать команду tcl и попросить интерпретатор выполнить ее. Это мост между python и tcl.

Данная команда позволяет изменить размеры окна и границы, цвет фона окна и границы:

configure - это команда которую фолучает интерпретатор tcl с параметрами.

```
root.tk.call(root,"configure"
,"-height","100"
,"-width","100"
,"-highlightthickness", 3
,"-highlightcolor","black"
,"-highlightbackground","black"
);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, достаточно развернуто?